# Run command on one server when a file updates on another

Tags: puppet

I want to update a service on a server (server B) when a file changes on a different server (server A).  I am using stored configs with PuppetDB.
When I do something like the code below I get the following error message

> Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid relationship: File[/etc/test.txt] { notify => Exec[command_on different_server] }, because Exec[command_on different_server] is exported but not collected

Am I on the right track?  I can't seem to figure it out how to do this.

```
class serverA {
  file { "/etc/test.txt":
    mode   => 644,
    source => "puppet:///modules/nagios/test.txt",
    notify => Exec["command_on different_server"],
  }

  @@exec { "command_on_different_server":
    command => "/usr/bin/command_whaterver",
    tag     => "tag_command",
  }
}

class serverB {
  Exec <<| tag == "tag_command" |>> {}
}
```

Comment: If you have Puppet Enterprise then you can use the orchestrator for this, although it would be overkill. Otherwise, you need to do as the error message says and collect the exported resource so the master can communicate what happened to the other server. Also, you need to have your `mode` attribute as a string.